# Android Studio notifications not being displayed

Tags: java, android

I have a button which, when pressed 5 times will create a user notification.  I am able to get the app to run however when pressing the button, I can see that the "counter" is incrementing but when >=5 there is not any notification being displayed.  I have entered into AndroidManifest.xml these lines:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

Below is my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.enetapplications.localnotifications;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.Manifest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    public final String CHANNEL_ID = "1_" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    int counter = 0;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                requestPermission();

                counter++;
                button.setText("" + counter);
                if (counter >= 5) {
                    startNotification();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void startNotification() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Channel Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_alert_24)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Notification Text")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManagerCompat compat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
        if (compat.areNotificationsEnabled()) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                compat.notify(1, builder.build());
            }
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.VIBRATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.VIBRATE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                startNotification();
            }
        } else {
            startNotification();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startNotification();
            } else {
                // Handle permission denied
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If notifications are not being displayed in Android Studio, there are    a few possible reasons and troubleshooting steps you can try:
Ensure that notifications are enabled in Android Studio. Go to File    -> Settings (or Preferences on macOS) -> Appearance &       Behavior -> Notifications. Make sure that the desired notification       types are set    to "Log Errors" or a higher level.
Confirm that your system's notification settings allow Android Studio    to display notifications. On your Android device, go to       Settings ->    Apps -> Android Studio [-](https://thefurniturevilla.co.uk/)> Notifications. Ensure that      notifications    are allowed, and the desired notification channels      are enabled.
Sometimes, a simple restart can resolve notification issues. Close    Android Studio completely and reopen it to see if the       notifications    start appearing.
Android Studio's Event Log can provide information about any errors    or issues that may be affecting notifications. Go to View      -> Tool    Windows -> Event Log. Look for any relevant error messages or    notifications related to notifications.
Make sure you are using the latest version of Android Studio. Check    for updates and install any available updates to ensure you     have the    most up-to-date version of the IDE.
If you have enabled "Power Save" mode in Android Studio, it may    suppress certain notifications. Disable this mode by going to    File    ->    Power Save Mode and unchecking the option.
If you are expecting specific notifications in your code,    double-check that you have implemented them correctly. Review your       code for any issues that might be preventing the notifications from      being triggered.
In some cases, antivirus software or firewall settings can interfere    with Android Studio's notifications. Temporarily disable    these tools    and check if the notifications start appearing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logic error in `startNotification()`. `compat.areNotificationsEnabled()` always returns false if app has no notification permissions! Also `requestPermission()` function is irrelevant, because the code already asks for permissions in `startNotification()`.

Button click listener doesn't need to call `requestPermission()`:

```java
button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter++;
        button.setText("" + counter);
        if (counter >= 5) {
            startNotification();
        }
    }
});
```

And you can simplify `startNotification()`:

```java
public void startNotification() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //Request permissions and return
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }
    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Channel Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_alert_24)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Notification Text")
            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID) //You might want to include this
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this)
            .notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

I also noticed you're using `CHANNEL_ID` wrong. This code will create a new notification channel every time you launch the app:

[image: Notification categories]

Instead, just set `CHANNEL_ID` to some constant:

```java
public final String CHANNEL_ID = "Default channel";
```

Comment: Thank you @Remc4 - very helpful and targeted.  It does appear that the error was the phone not displaying the notifications - odd in that I thought the code would prompt notification feedback regardless of phone's internal settings.  Thank you again.